# Spring Boot @Transactional behaviour when method marked @Transactional called from method having ongoing parent transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarlint

Here is pseudocode/flow of some part of my app:

```
@Transactional
updateResource(String whatToUpdate,Resource resourceToUpdate){
//method to update a resource , can be called individually or from other method like methodStep3()
}


@Transactional
complexOperationMethod (){
//step1: finding List<Resource> each having ref=uuid value from db
//step2: for each Resource go to db and find its id , replace ref in first step by id 
//step3: insert back the updated List<Resource> in db  

}

methodStep2(){
//for each Resource go to db and find its id , replace ref in first step by id 
}

methodStep3(){
//insert back the updated List<Resource> in db 
//use already defined updateResource(whatToUpdate,resource) method to avoid code duplication
}
All methods within same instance
```

Now if complexOperationMethod() is called , a new Transaction will start and it will continue to 
methods methodStep2 and methodStep3 without marking them @Transactional as stated here https://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Transactional-method-calling-another-method-without-Transactional-anotation

But if methodStep3() is not marked with @Transactional , sonar throwing blocker error "@Transactional requirement is incompatible with the one for this method".

Should i go ahead and mark methodStep3() @Transactional , will it work as expected and not break anything in future when update will be running in some update() request and complexOperationMethod() for other request. Has anybody tried this use-case before? TIA.

Comment: To understand in your use-case is `complexOperationMethod()` calling `methodStep3()` when the exception is thrown . Could you please update the error stack to the question?

Comment: I am getting a Blocker Bug from Sonar "Methods should not call same-class methods with incompatible "@Transactional" values" and no exception being thrown as such.To understand the behaviour need to send two request simultaneously one for update() and other for complexOperationMethod(). But overall is this application of @Transactional annotation ok?